# How should I avoid this "Warning: Failed prop type: You provided a `value` prop to a form field without an `onChange` handler."

Tags: javascript, reactjs

It seems that *in React* every `<input>` with a value attribute must have an `onChange` handler. I wonder what is the best practice in the following snippet to avoid the boring message.

```js
import React,{Component} from 'react';

class SpellTest extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
      chars:Array.from(props.word,()=>{return "?"})
    };
    this.handleInput=this.handleInput.bind(this);
  }
  handleInput(e){
    
    let key=e.key
    this.setState(preState=>{return {chars:preState.chars.map((k,i)=>{return this.props.word.charAt(i)===key?key:k})};})
  }
  render(){
    return <div>
        <h1>{this.props.hint}</h1>
        <input value={this.state.chars.join("")} onKeyPress={this.handleInput} onChange={()=>{}}/>
      </div>
  }
}

export default SpellTest;

//usage:
//<SpellTest word="hello" hint="你好"/>
//https://create-react-client.glitch.me/spell
```

Comment: If you don't want to post the content of that input anywhere you could just use a `<p>` to display the value. Your `<input>` isn't editable anyways so there is no real reason to use it.

Comment: If you don't wish to have an `onChange` handler then there is no meaning of keeping `onChange={()=>{}}`

Comment: The <input>, unlike <p>, will allow the soft keyboard to pop up when focused on mobile.

Comment: I am also having this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I asked the question for the following reasons:

1. The best way to obtain each key typed into the input field should be
   `onKeyXXX` like `onKeyPress` or `onKeyDown`(I failed to get the key
   value from `onChange`)
2. React complains about the absence of the `onChange` which means
   there should be a pattern to allow `onChange` to coorperate with the
   `onKeyXXX` handlers but I don't know how

Finally I realized that the keypress event is not supported by chrome android. So I have to change the code as follows:

```js
import React,{Component} from 'react';

class SpellTest extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
      chars:Array.from(props.word,()=>{return "?"})
    };
    
    this.handleChange=this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }
  
  handleChange(e){
    
    let str=e.target.value;
    let str2=this.state.chars.join("");
    let index=[...str].findIndex((k,i)=>{return str.slice(0,i)+str.slice(i+1)===str2})
    
    if(index!==-1){
      this.setState(preState=>{return {chars:preState.chars.map((k,i)=>{return this.props.word.charAt(i)===str[index]?str[index]:k})};})
    }
  }
  render(){
    return <div>
        <h1>{this.props.hint}</h1>
        <input value={this.state.chars.join("")}  onChange={this.handleChange}/>
      </div>
  }
}

export default SpellTest;
```

Answer (score -3):

Inputs should have `onChange` to know how to change a `value` data. Just change `onKeyPress` to `onChange` and everything should work fine.

Comment: onChange does not fire when the person hits "Enter"